# I don't receive `transfer` data quering `get_action_traces` on dfuse

Tags: dfuse

.getActionTraces({account: "eosbetdice11"}, {start_block: Number(process.env.START_BLOCK)})

here's the response

[image]

I'm using both the ts library (https://github.com/dfuse-io/eosws-js), no filtering on the `action_name`, but there is no `transfer` info, tried the go library as well, same issue.

Comment: What is the value effective value of `Number(process.env.START_BLOCK)` exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the reason why there is no `transfer` action returned is simply because  the transfers you see on `eosbetdice11` account are from the `eosio.token` contract.

Here are the ABI action names available on the `eosbetdice11` contract:

`$ eosc get abi eosbetdice11 | jq .abi.actions[].name
"initcontract"
"togglepause"
"setbonus"
"killbonus"
"newrandkey"
"suspendbet"
"resolvebet"
"betreceipt"
"refundbet"`

As you can see, there is no `transfer` action in this contract. The `account` parameter in `get_action_traces` is used to filter out all actions performed on the contract active on `account`.

In your `get_action_traces`, you are requesting `account: eosbetdice11`, the `transfer` action will never happen on this contract.

If you provide `{ account: "eosio.token", receiver: "eosbetdice11" }` instead, you will receive all `eosio.token` actions for which the receiver of the action was `eosbetdice11`. You will get transfers in those cases that "affected" `eosbetdice11` account.

Add `action: "transfer"` if you only care about `transfer` actions.